# Sorting a binary search tree on different key value

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Say I have a binary tree with the following definition for a node.

```
struct node
{
 int key1 ;
 int key2 ;
}
```

The binary search tree is created on the basis of key1. Now is it possible to rearrange the binary search tree on basis of key2 in O(1) space. Although I can do this in variable space using an array of pointers to nodes.

The actual problem where I require this is "counting number of occurrences of unique words in a file and displaying the result in decreasing order of frequency."
Here, a BST node is

```
{
 char *word;
 int freq ;
}
```

The BST is first created on basis of alphabetic order of words and finally I want it on basis of freq.

Am I wrong at choice of data structure i.e a BST?

Comment: you can not sort your BST by freqs because each freq must be unique. That wont be true in your case.

Comment: Nick D: If you look at common BST implementations, it is often defined as "left child is <, right child is >=". Values need not be unique. For maps, yes, keys need to be unique, but I don't believe the asker is really using keys in the "mapping keys to values" sense. If I'm wrong, then yes, you may be right that he is sunk. :(

Comment: Agor, I think you are wrong. In a BST we can not get multiple results. If we find a node we stop. We don't examine the childs.

Comment: That is only if you are looking for a single value.  If you are walking the binary tree in in-order, then you don't stop and this will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a new tree sorted by `freq` and push there all elements popping them from an old tree.

That *could be* O(1) though likely more like `O(log N)` which isn't big anyway.

Also, I don't know how you call it in C#, but in Python you can use list but sort it by two different keys in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Using a HashTable (Java) or Dictionary (.NET) or equivalent data structure in your language of choice (hash_set or hash_map in STL) will give you O(1) inserts during the counting phase, unlike the binary search tree which would be somewhere from O(log n) to O(n) on insert depending on whether it balances itself. If performance is really that important just make sure you try to initialize your HashTable to a large enough size that it won't need to resize itself dynamically, which can be expensive.

As for listing by frequency, I can't immediately think of a tricky way to do that without involving a sort, which would be O(n log n).

Comment: You could maintain 2 data structures in paralel: one hastable to have quick lookup, and a map/sorted array to have your data well sorted. But every add/remove operation will need you to launch them on each data structure in 2 separate threads if you want to keep the best of the 2 world. Depending on Neeraj needs, it could be harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Map, BST are good if you need to have sorted output for your dictionnary.

And it is good if you need to mix up add, remove and lookup operations.
I don't think this is your need here. You load the dictionnary, sort it, then do only look up in it, that's right ?
In this case a sorted array is probably a better container. (See Item 23 from [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629) from Scott Meyer).
*(Update: simply consider that a map could generate more memory cache misses than a sorted array, as an array get its data contiguous in memory, and as each node in a map contain 2 pointers to other nodes in the map. When your objects are simple and take not much space in memory, a sorted vector is probable a better option. I warmly recommand you to read that item from Meyer's book)*

About the kind of sort you are talking about, you will need that algorithm from the stl:
[stable_sort](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stable_sort.html).
The idea is to sort the dictionnary, then sort with stable_sort() on the frequence key.

It will give something like that (not tested actually, but you got the idea):

```
struct Node
{
char * word;
int key;
};

bool operator < (const Node& l, const Node& r)
{
    return std::string(l.word) < std::string(r.word));
}

bool freq_comp(const Node& l, const Node& r)
{
    return l.key < r.key;
}

std::vector<node> my_vector;
... // loading elements
sort(vector.begin(), vector.end());
stable_sort(vector.begin(), vector.end(), freq_comp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion for re-balancing the tree based off of the new keys (well, I have 2 suggestions).

The first and more direct one is to somehow adapt Heapsort's "bubble-up" function (to use Sedgewick's name for it). Here is a link to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), there they call it "sift-up". It is not designed for an entirely-unbalanced tree (which is what you'd need), but I believe it demonstrates the basic flow of an in-place reordering of a tree. It may be a bit hard to follow because the tree is in fact stored in array rather than a tree (though the logic in a sense treats it as a tree) --- perhaps, though, you'll find such an array-based representation is best! Who knows.

The more crazy-out-there suggestion of mine is to use a splay tree. I think they're nifty, and here's the [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree). Basically, whichever element you access is "bubbled up" to the top, but it maintains the BST invariants. So you maintain the original Key1 for building the initial tree, but hopefully most of the "higher-frequency" values will also be near the top. This may not be enough (as all it will mean is that higher-frequency words will be "near" the top of the tree, not necessarily ordered in any fashion), but if you do happen to have or find or make a tree-balancing algorithm, it may run a lot faster on such a splay tree.

Hope this helps! And thank you for an interesting riddle, this sounds like a good Haskell project to me..... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this in O(1) space, but not in O(1) time ;-)

Even though re-arranging a whole tree recursively until it is sorted again seems possible, it is probably not very fast - it may be O(n) at best, probably worse in practice. So you might get a better result by adding all nodes to an array once you are done with the tree and just sorting this array using quicksort on frequency (which will be O(log n) on average). At least that's what I would do. Even tough it takes extra space it sounds more promising to me than re-arranging the tree in place.

Comment: But O(1) space is the *fun* way! :D

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could consider is to build **two** trees.  One indexed by `word`, one indexed by `freq`.

As long as the tree nodes contain a **pointer** to the data node, you could access if via the `word`-based tree to update the info, but later access it by the `freq`-based tree to output.

Although, if speed is really that important, I'd be looking to get rid of the string as a key.  String comparisons are notoriously slow.

If speed is not important, I think your best bet is to gather the data based on `word` and re-sort based on `freq` as yves has suggested.

Comment: You can even still have the data live in the nodes, if your nodes are simultaneously members of both trees (`struct node { data; struct node *word_left, *word_right, *freq_left, *freq_right }`)